# Can you help me identify this set?

Tags: set-identification

I have this lone bag, and I think it contains a full vehicle, but it's from a bigger set, I believe, because of the number 2. Anyone know what set? I need instructions.
(Dear Lego, please put set numbers on bags!)
Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: +1 Just because you asked TLG to put set numbers on the bags. I totally agree with that.

Answer (score 12):

This bag is part of Set **76015-1** from 2014

- **Ultimate Spider-Man, 
  Doc Ock Truck Heist**

[image]